# How to get android vision sample camera preview to fit to screen

Tags: android, android-vision

I tried making the preview match parent and tried the fill but I cannot make it work. There is a large grey line to the right of the screen

Comment: Show your layout file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In CameraSourcePreview.java comment this lines of code:

```
    if (childHeight > layoutHeight) {
        childHeight = layoutHeight;
        childWidth = (int)(((float) layoutHeight / (float) height) * width);
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem. The solution from @Mindshifter worked for me, but you can have a look here for more comments (and I've posted a similar solution there too):

https://github.com/googlesamples/android-vision/issues/23